# Writing Undertow access.log to non-default location in Wildfly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

I am new to the undertow web server in Wildfly.

I am running Wildfly8.1 in domain mode and attempting to have undertow write the access log to a non-default location.  currently the default is directory="${jboss.server.log.dir}".  I am trying to setup the access-log attribute "directory" to work like this diretory="${custom.jboss.server.log.dir}.  I have this variable defind the the host-slave.xml as:

```
<server name="myserver" group="mygroup" auto-start="true">
<paths>
    <path name="custom.jboss.server.log.dir" path="/apps/logs/servers/server_mars_8443/logs"/>
</paths>
</server>
```

In the domain.xml I have:

```
<host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
 <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
 <access-log directory="${custom.jboss.server.log.dir}" prefix="access.log_" suffix="" pattern="%t %h %l %u %r %s %b %T" worker="default"/>
 ...
</host>
```

This setup works in JBoss EAP  6.2.

But, in Wildfly 8.1, I get the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "undertow"),
("server" => "default-server"),
("host" => "default-host")
```

]) - failure description: {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host is missing [jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.access-log]"]}
2014-09-25 16:25:33,611 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("host" => "default-host"),
    ("location" => "/")
]) - failure description: {"JBAS014879: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
    "Services that were unable to start:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.location./"],
    "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.undertow.server.default-server.default-host.access-log"]
}}

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you forgot to specify the property for the `default-server`, on `domain.xml` ? Your exception is about the `default-server`, not about `myserver`.

Comment: The default server is specificed in domain.xml.  Please see below.

Comment: <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.1">
                <buffer-cache name="default"/>
                <server name="default-server">
                    <ajp-listener name="ajp" socket-binding="ajp"/>
                    <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
                    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                        <access-log directory="${custom.jboss.server.log.dir}" prefix="access.log_" pattern="%t %h %l %u %r %s %b %T" worker="default" />
                        <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>

Comment: That's my point :) You don't seem to have defined the `custom.jboss.server.log.dir` on it, so, when you say that the default-host should log its requests to this place, the `default-server` doesn't knows what it means.

Comment: Yes, this is defined in the host-slave.xml file.    <server name="my_server" group="group1" auto-start="true">
            <paths>
                <path name="custom.jboss.server.log.dir" path="/apps/logs/my_server/serverlogs"/>
            </paths></server>

Comment: That path is defined only for the host `my_server`. Try defining the `path` *also* for the `default-server`.